# Chopper amplifier design - why is the output not synchronous with the chopper frequency?

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit, cmos

I'm trying to design, for the first time, a chopper amplifier based on the following structure:
[image]

I've already designed all blocks, and now I'm simulating the entire system (transient, pss, etc.) in buffer mode, with a DC input equal to VDD/2, and chopper freq. equal to 16kHz (that freq. is greater than the 1/f corner of the core stage G2+G1.)

During transient simulation I noticed a strange behavior (I think) of the output; in practice I expect that the output should be synchronous with the chopping frequency, but in reality the behavior is the following:

[image]

Is it correct that the output oscillates faster than the chopping frequency? If yes, do you know what the problem is?

Comment: With all choppers held in one mode, are your amps stable from the point of view of `stb`?

Comment: @nanofarad The core stage (G2+G1) is a I/O rail-to-rail class-AB OA with PM of 68°; G4 has Loop PM of 86° (compensated); G5 has Loop PM of 76° (compensated)